# Surround Game in Java using enum class - how to find a winner

Tags: java, enums

I am creating a "Surround Game" for a class project. The idea is that if a player is surrounded on all four sides (if applicable) then that player looses and the player surrounding them will win. This is an example of what the wins should look like. I am doing mine a bit different because I am using icons to display instead of numbers, but it's the same idea.  In all cases below, player 1 wins.

[image]

So my issue is in the surroundGame class, I'm not sure how to tell it if there is a winner. I have an enum class with the cell icons, one being player 1, etc.

```
public enum Cell {
ONE, TWO, EMPTY;
}
```

Additionally, I have an enum gameStatus class:

```
public enum GameStatus {
 PLAYER1_WON, PLAYER2_WON, TIE, IN_PROGRESS
}
```

This is the surroundGame class where the problem is in the methods called isWinner and isSurrounded.

```
package project2;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.*;


public class SurroundGame {
private Cell[][] board;
private GameStatus status;
private int size;
private Cell turn;
private Cell whoStarts;

some code edited out....

private GameStatus isWinner() {

    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            if (board[r][c] == Cell.EMPTY) {
                return GameStatus.IN_PROGRESS;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            if (isSurrounded(Cell.ONE)) {
                return GameStatus.PLAYER1_WON;
            }
            if (isSurrounded(Cell.TWO)) {
                return GameStatus.PLAYER2_WON;
            }
        }
    }
        return GameStatus.TIE;
}

private boolean isSurrounded(Cell type) {
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            if (board[r][c + 1] == type && board[r][c - 1] == type) {
                if (board[r + 1][c] == type && board[r - 1][c] == type) {
                    return true;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


public GameStatus getGameStatus() {
    return status;
}

}
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to tell when a player has won. When I test the GUI, if it ends in a tie (no one wins) that works correctly, as do all other functions so I know the only problem is the specific instances where a player actually wins. I am using the helper method isSurrounded in the isWinner method, but I must not be using the logic of the loops correctly because it isn't working. I have tried using two helper methods, one to see if the column of the cell is surrounded, and a second to see if the row of the cell is surrounded, then checked both of those in isWinner to produce a winner, but that also did not work.
Additionally, I figured out how to explicitly declare a upper left corner win, but that would be a lot of work to code for each win, especially because the size of the game board can vary between 3 and 10, and I eventually plan to add multiple players. But regardless, here's how I did that in the isWinner method

```
int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    if (board[row][col] == Cell.ONE && board[row][col + 1] == Cell.TWO
            && board[row + 1][col] == Cell.TWO) {
        return GameStatus.PLAYER2_WON;
    }
    if (board[row][col] == Cell.TWO && board[row][col + 1] == Cell.ONE
            && board[row + 1][col] == Cell.ONE) {
        return GameStatus.PLAYER1_WON;
    }
```

I really don't want to do that for every possible scenario, and I'm sure there's a more efficient way to find the winner with loops like I was trying above. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Just a suggestion. It might be easier to pad your board out with extra rows and columns around the edges so that there is always a cell above, below, to the left, and to the right of every cell on the board. You wouldn't display these extra cells, but you would populate them with a special value, call it "BLOCK", that blocks either player. Also, in your enum, provide a method that tells whether a value blocks that value. ONE would return true for TWO or BLOCK, TWO returns true for ONE or BLOCK. This makes the logic much more regular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you in Jags class too?

I just finished the project and used the following as my `isSurrounded()` method. It's certainly not as complex as the others above but it gets the point acrossed for a lower level course:

```
private boolean isSurrounded(Cell type, Cell other) {
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            if(board[r][c] == type){
                int count = 0;
                int win_count = 0;
                log(c + " " + r);
                if((r-1) >= 0 && (r - 1) < size){
                    win_count++;
                    if (board[r - 1][c] == other) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                if((r + 1) >= 0 && (r + 1) < size){
                    win_count++;
                    if (board[r + 1][c] == other) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                if((c + 1) >= 0 && (c + 1) < size){
                    win_count++;
                    if (board[r][c + 1] == other) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }

                if((c - 1) >= 0 && (c - 1) < size){
                    win_count++;
                    if (board[r][c - 1] == other) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if(win_count == count){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm in his class too. I finally figured it out using a bunch of helper methods to check each section for wins separately. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop in isWinner() you are checking every position for an empty cell. Since your winning solutions will no doubt still have open cells it is returning IN_PROGRESS before you are checking isSurrounded(). You should check if any position is surrounded first then check if the game is in a tie or still continuing.

Also, You are looping the call to isSurround and looping inside isSurround. This is a lot of unnecessary calling and looping, just call isSurround outside a loop with each cell type and let that function do all the looping as you have it set.

This should work a little better

```
private GameStatus isWinner(){
    if(isSurrounded(Cell.ONE)){
        return GameStatus.PLAYER1_WON;
    }
    if(isSurrounded(Cell.TWO)){
        return GameStatus.PLAYER2_WON;
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            if (board[r][c] == Cell.EMPTY) {
                return GameStatus.IN_PROGRESS;
            }
        }
    return GameStatus.TIE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will make life easier for yourself if you encapsulate your coordinates (row, col) in a class. You can then implement methods such as `listSurroundingCoordinates`:

```
class Coord {
    private final int row;
    private final int col;
    private final static int SIZE = 4;

    public List<Coord> listSurroundingCoordinates() {
        List<Coord> coords = new ArrayList<>();
        if (row > 0)
            coords.add(new Coords(row - 1, col));
        if (row < SIZE - 1)
            coords.add(new Coords(row + 1, col));
        if (col > 0)
            coords.add(new Coords(row, col - 1));
        if (col < SIZE - 1)
            coords.add(new Coords(row, col + 1));
        return coords;
    }

    // need equals and hashCode to be defined
}
```

Your board then becomes a `Map<Coord, Player> board` - you don't need an 'empty' value any longer as that's represented by not having the coordinates in the map.

Once you've implemented that checking a win is a fairly simple matter (I've used Java 8 here):

```
public boolean hasWon(CellValue player) {
    return board.keySet().stream()
        .filter(c -> !board.get(c).equals(player))
        .filter(c -> c.listSurroundingCoords().stream()
            .allMatch(s -> board.containsKey(s) && board.get(s).equals(player)))
        .findAny().isPresent();
}
```

Let me know if you're not using Java 8 or must use arrays and I can post the equivalent using standard iteration and avoiding `Map`.